# Directory level .htaccess mod_rewrite stops vhost rewrites

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The following directive in my `vhost` file works fine when there is no `.htaccess` file.  But, when I introduce one it stops working.  How do I get the `vhost` rewrites to execute when the `htaccess` rewrite is `not-matched`?

From `vhost.conf`:

```
# Skip everything except html and json
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|json)$
RewriteRule .* - [L]
# If html exists (is cached)
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
# Otherwise pass it on the index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

From `/test/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} old_directory/.*$
RewriteRule (.*)$ old_missing.phtml [PT]
```

Requests for `/test/hello.json`...

...without `.htaccess`: is routed to `index.php` and returns the correct json.

...with `.htaccess`: returns a `404 Not Found`

Requests for `/text/old_hello.phtml`...

...without `.htaccess`: returns a `404 Not Found`

...with `.htaccess`: returns the contents of `old_missing.phtml`

Also, I tailed my rewrite log and it looks like it's doing what it should with the `.htaccess` rules (`trip per-dir prefix`, `applying pattern`, `RewriteCond => not-matched`, and `pass through`), but then it just stops.

For those who are inclined to ask "Why are you doing this?" there are two reasons 1) I'm getting paid and 2) we are migrating some ajax `.phtml` requests to a new ajax `.json` system so we need to pass back a message if the user is requesting files from the `old_directory` to first inform them of the changes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the following line into ALL your .htaccess files where you use Rewrite Rules:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions

Comment: I knew it was something simple.  Thanks.